# Inequalities about tripling and doubling sumsets

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics, integer-sequences

Let $A$ be a set of vectors in $\mathbb Z^d$ who $\mathbb R$-span is the whole $\mathbb R^d$. Let $s_i(A)$ denote the size of $A+A+\dots A$ ($i$ times). I am interested in the following:

> **Question 1**: Find sufficient conditions on  $A$ so we have: $s_3(A)\geq (d+2)s_2(A) -\binom{d+2}{2}s_1(A)+\binom{d+2}{3} $?

For $d=1$  $A$ is just a bunch of integers. Then the inequality $s_3(A)\geq 3s_2(A)-3s_1(A)+1$ occurs if they form an arithmetic progression (in fact, equality happens). I did not find  other examples, although admittedly I have not looked too hard (Seva pointed out in the comment that this hold for "generic" A). It is of course easy and classical that $s_2(A)\geq 2s_1(A)-1$.

A harder(?) question is:

> **Question 2**: Find sufficient conditions on $A$ so we have: $s_3(A)\geq (d+1)s_2(A) -\binom{d+1}{2}s_1(A)+\binom{d+1}{3} $?

This inequality is weaker than the one in Question 1. For $d=1$ it reads $s_3(A)\geq 2s_2(A)-s_1(A)$. In fact, I do not know any sequence that fails this.

Any pointer to relevant, similar inequalities in the literature would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is there any difference between your $s_i(A)$ and the quantity commonly denoted by $|iA|$ (the size of the $i$-fold sumset $iA$)?

Comment: No, I am just not sure what is the standard notation.

Comment: I do not understand then. For a set $A$ in a general position, one has $|3A|\sim |A|^3/6$, while $|2A|=O(|A|^2)$. Therefore, your inequalities hold true for any "typical" set, not necessarily an arithmetic progression or anything else of this sort?

Comment: I am interested in finding concrete sufficient condition. Even for $d=1$.

Comment: @Seva: I edited the question now. As you pointed out, the generic $A$ satisfies these inequalities. But, for example, does the inequality for Question 2 holds always when $d=1$? Thanks.

Comment: No, it does not. Take $A$ to be a subset of $[0,l]$ such that $2A=[0,2l]$. Then $|3A|+|A|\le 3l+|A|+1<4l+2=2|2A|$ provided $|A|<l+1$.

Comment: @Seva: cool. So is there any hope for a non-trivial sufficient condition? Anything in the literature?

Comment: There are lots of papers dealing with sumset inequalities, many of them due to Imre Ruzsa, but your particular inequalities hold almost always.

Comment: @Seva: that's a good hint, I will look up his papers. I would still like to know if there are some criteria other than probabilistic ones (although they are probably the best one can say).

Comment: You should check this paper of Gyarmati, Matolcsi and Ruzsa where they prove that $|3A| \geq 3/2|2A| - O(1)$. This was originally proved by Lev in https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82292093.pdf. It is weaker than what you want, but the proof is short